# How to switch first word and last word in a string by oracle

Tags: string, oracle, switch-statement, revert

I need a help. Could you give me an advice for switch the first word and last word in a string by oracle

For example:

Input:

Column 1

apple is a red this

Expected output:

Column 2

this is a red apple

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `REGEXP_REPLACE` with capture groups.  Capture the first and last words, along with any possible content in the middle.  Then replace with the first and last words switched.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(Col1, '^(\w+)(.*?)(\w+)$', '\3\2\1')
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo